# Django Jenkins raises WebDriverException when processed to Selenium server

Tags: python, django, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I start Selenium server hub by command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role hub
```

and Selenium server node by command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=htmlunit
```

Then i'm trying to execute code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
server =  'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
dc = DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT
browser = webdriver.Remote(server, dc)
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
```

Everything is ok after this.
But when i'm trying to start Jenkins test:

```
from django.test import TestCase, LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.common import proxy
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver

class SeleniumTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        p = proxy.Proxy({
        'proxyType': proxy.ProxyType().MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': '127.0.0.1:4444',
        })

        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().HTMLUNIT
        cls.selenium = WebDriver(desired_capabilities=capabilities, proxy=p)
        super(SeleniumTest, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(SeleniumTest, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_javascript_basket(self):
        self.selenium.get('http://localhost:8000')
```

I'm getting following error, contained in traceback:

> WebDriverException: Message: u'\n\n\nERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved\n\n\n\n
>
> ## ERROR
>
> \n
>
> ### The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> \n\n
>
> ---
>
> \n\n\n
>
> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: a href="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session" localhost:4444/wd/hub/session ap\n\n\n
>
> **Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed.**
>
> \n

\n\nThe system returned: *(111) Connection refused*\n\n

The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.

\n\n

Your cache administrator is webmaster.

\n\n
\n\n\n

---

\n\n

Generated Mon, 10 Jun 2013 04:36:42 GMT by localhost (squid/3.1.6)

\n\n\n'

What's going on? Why connect to Selenium server from Jenkins test isn't working?

```
python==2.7.3
Django==1.5
django-jenkins==0.14.0
selenium==2.33.0
```

**UPDATE:** If i'm using Firefox WebDriver instead of HTMLUNIT, Firefox opens after line

```
cls.selenium = WebDriver(desired_capabilities=capabilities, proxy=p)
```

, but later raises above-described exception.

**RESOLVED**
I simply add to `setUpClass()` method:

```
import os
. . .
    def setUpClass(cls):
        os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Just a possibility... Do you have admin rights on the system?

Comment: @zen11625 Can you might post you way as an answer. That this question is not more unanswered. Thannks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem this way (used a *phantom-js* instead of *HTMLUNIT*, because it's the only remaining stable version of code).

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from os import environ


class SeleniumTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    __test__ = False    

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'  # The key point

        cls.selenium = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--proxy-type=none'])    
        super(SeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.close()
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(SeleniumTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()


class TestFoo(SeleniumTestCase):    
    def setUp(self):
        # do something before every test method runs
        pass
    def test_foo(self):
        # test
        pass
```